# How to speed up plt.scatter() with colormap?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, scatter

I want to plot the coordinates (following with `x0` and `y0`)

```
colors = cm.rainbow(np.linspace(0, 1, len(x0)))
for k in np.arange(len(x0)):
    for i in range(len(x0[k])):
        plt.scatter(x0[k][i], y0[k][i], color=colors[k], s = 2)
```

This loop working approximately 50000-60000 times.

But it takes time to finish **2 hours.**
I run this script on my macbook air m1.

I think it very slow to run this script.

Do you have any solutions to speed up this code or another libraries to scatter coordinates ex. `ggplot` etc.?

This is some information for `x0` and `y0`.

```
for i in range(10000,10021):
        print(f'{x0[i]} {y0[i]}')

-----------------------------------
Result :
[145.5, 146] [39.5, 39]
[146.5] [39.5]
[147] [39]
[147.5] [39.5]
[148.5] [39.5]
[149.5] [39.5]
[150, 150.5] [39, 39.5]
[151] [39]
[151.5] [39.5]
[152.5] [39.5]
[153] [39]
[153.5, 154] [39.5, 39]
[154.5] [39.5]
[155, 155.5] [39, 39.5]
[156] [39]
[156.5] [39.5]
[157] [39]
[157.5] [39.5]
[158.5] [39.5]
[159] [39]
[159.5] [39.5]
```

plt.show() should be (Don't have white and black spot):

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using pandas to [**`explode()`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) the 2D data/colors into long-form vectors. Then you can replace the loop with a single call to `scatter()`:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'x0': x0, 'color': cm.rainbow(np.linspace(0, 1, len(x0))).tolist()})
df = df.explode('x0')
df['y0'] = pd.Series(y0).explode()

plt.scatter(df.x0, df.y0, color=df.color, s=2)
```

The long-form dataframe will look something like this:

```
      x0    y0                                              color
0  145.5  39.5                               [0.5, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0]
0    146    39                               [0.5, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0]
1  146.5  39.5  [0.40588235294117647, 0.1473016980546375, 0.99...
2    147    39  [0.303921568627451, 0.30315267411304353, 0.988...
3  147.5  39.5  [0.2019607843137255, 0.45124405704532283, 0.97...
4  148.5  39.5  [0.09999999999999998, 0.5877852522924731, 0.95...
5  149.5  39.5  [0.0019607843137254832, 0.7092813076058534, 0....
6    150    39  [0.09607843137254901, 0.8053809193888326, 0.89...
6  150.5  39.5  [0.09607843137254901, 0.8053809193888326, 0.89...
7    151    39  [0.19803921568627447, 0.8896040127307095, 0.85...
...  ...   ...                                                ...
```

Comment: It gives `IndexError: tuple index out of range`

Comment: I just updated the result of `x0` and `y0` on the post. I think it's useful. Thank you.

Comment: @ChampRock updated with a `pandas`-based solution

Comment: Your lastest method works for me. It takes only **1 second** to plot. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It is much faster to pass the inner lists to the plot as a whole. As you still want to set the color per `k`, you can easliy avoid the `i` loop. Assuming the dimension of `i` is not negligible, this should speed up the process considerably.

```
colors = cm.rainbow(np.linspace(0, 1, len(x0)))
for k in np.arange(len(x0)):
        plt.scatter(x0[k], y0[k], color=colors[k], s = 2)
```

Edit: As the dimension of `k` is much higher than `i`, switching dimensions before reduces the number of scatters even more.

```
import pandas as pd
#...
colors = cm.rainbow(np.linspace(0, 1, len(x0)))
dfx = pd.DataFrame(x0).T
dfy = pd.DataFrame(y0).T

for i in np.arange(len(x0)):
        plt.scatter(dfx[i], dfy[i], color=colors[i], s = 2)
```

Comment: I try this method before. But this method still takes the same of time (~ 2 hours).

Comment: Ok, that is surprising. I tried it with random data where `i` and `k` had similar dimension. What are the actual dimensions of the 2d lists?

Comment: It has ~50000 row x 1-3 col. So it will do not plt.scatter() more than 150000 times. and if you set specific color (every point use the same color). It won't be a problem